# iTerm always asks for user login before loading the shell

Tags: macos, iterm

I'm using macOS on Sonoma, and for as long as I remember, iTerm2 prompts me to log in with **user** *and* password each time before it loads the shell. On restart, it requires the user login again. The same does not happen with the native Terminal.

I have asked on Unix stack exchange, with no success. I have tried the solution given in the post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767394/596618 using its source.

I thought the issue might have been in having the terminal installed in `/Applications`instead of `~/Applications` but it was not it.

Likewise, I removed `/Users/kamil/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` (copy is [here](https://pastebin.com/5rAVuzMY)) and iTerm with default configuration did not prompt the login and password, but I did not find any setting in the UI — going through them all which could have been responsible.

[image: Screenshot-2024-02-06-at-14-59-42.png]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `iterm2.plist`, you seem to have one tab open which runs `login -fp "kamilszafraniak"` each time you start up iTerm.